# Using Render hosting app to deploy my project- Error Cannot find module

Tags: deployment, hosting, render.com

Follows **Heroku** becoming a paid app, I am trying other options.
Does anyone have experience uploading a MongoDB server-based project to **"Render" Application Hosting**?

This is the repo I want to deploy:
https://github.com/myyoss/FUNDLE_A_WORDLE_CLONE

On the app **settings** I use for the **Build Command: "yarn"** (and it seems to works cause I get "Build successful" message).

But for the **Start Command** I can't get the correct command/path.
I keep getting this error:

==> Build successful :

Oct 7 06:41:33 PM ==> Deploying…

Oct 7 06:42:01 PM ==> Starting service with `‘node dist/server.js’`

Oct 7 06:42:06 PM `internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888`

Oct 7 06:42:06 PM throw err;

Oct 7 06:42:06 PM ^

Oct 7 06:42:06 PM

Oct 7 06:42:06 PM **Error: Cannot find module `‘…/routes/userRoutes’`**

**Can someone please take a look at the repo LINK and tell me what I'm doing wrong?**

On an other project I used "node dist/server.js" for the Start Command and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks of searching for a solution to the problem, I found it! As silly as it sounds I'll write it here, maybe it will save one of you guys wasting a lot of precious time. The problem was that the build folder was not updated, and all the changes and corrections I made actually remained as they are in production. **After deleting the build folder and created it again the problem was solved :)**

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be [here](https://github.com/myyoss/FUNDLE_A_WORDLE_CLONE/blob/main/dist/server.js#L6), where you use `"../routes/userRoutes"`. You want to use `"./routes/userRoutes"` since the location of that file is relative to the root directory, `./`

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34247468/node-error-cannot-find-module-routes) may be helpful re: routing errors, and Render's [quickstart](https://render.com/docs/deploy-node-express-app) for Node/Express is also worth a look.

Comment: Thanks Dnilasor! You were right regarding "./routes/userRoutes", unfortunately it wasn't enough:) same with the links you have provided, I have tried them but the same error comes up... I really can't understand what is wrong:(